# how to reinitialise global variable in flask app python

Tags: python, flask

Here is the Flask app.py

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request
import trainer
app = Flask(__name__)
 

@app.route('/success/<name>')
def success(name):
    gValue = trainer.myFunction()
    name = name + gValue
    return 'welcome %s' % name
 
 
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.form['nm']
        return redirect(url_for('success', name=user))
    else:
        user = request.args.get('nm')
        return redirect(url_for('success', name=user))
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

HTML file

```
<html>
<body>   
    <form action = "http://localhost:5000/login" method = "post">
<p>Enter Name:</p>
<p><input type = "text" name = "nm" /></p>
<p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

trainer.py

```
from utils import sumValue

def myFunction():
   pullValue = sumValue()
   return pullValue
```

utils.py

```
aggregateValue = " defaultValue"

def sumValue():
    global aggregateValue
    x = " mainValue"
    x1 = x + aggregateValue
    aggregateValue = " modifiedValue"
    x2 = x1 + aggregateValue
    print(x2)
    return x2
```

running the app

```
C:\test>python app.py
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2024 16:12:57] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
 mainValue defaultValue modifiedValue
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2024 16:12:57] "GET /success/Value HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2024 16:15:59] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
 mainValue modifiedValue modifiedValue
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Jan/2024 16:15:59] "GET /success/Value HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

in the first run we get

mainValue defaultValue modifiedValue

in 2nd run

mainValue modifiedValue modifiedValue

as the 2nd run is a fresh run, I expect the middle value should be defaultValue instead of modifiedValue,

The global declaration in utils.py is not getting initialized during 2nd run,

If we Ctrl+C and start again, memory is cleared to get defaultValue

May I know how to initialize the global variable here?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code, you can add a line to reset the variable, you can do this before finishing the sumValue() function.

```
aggregateValue = " defaultValue"

def sumValue():
    global aggregateValue
    x = " mainValue"
    x1 = x + aggregateValue
    aggregateValue = " modifiedValue"
    # Print the variable [MOD]
    print("===> " + aggregateValue)
    x2 = x1 + aggregateValue
    print(x2)
    aggregateValue = " defaultValue"
    # Print the variable [RESET]
    print("$$$$> " + aggregateValue)
    return x2
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Flask app is continuously running, once the global variable is modified, it retains the value for the entire execution.

You can keep the global variable and use local variable if it is suitable to your use case.

```py
aggregateValue = " defaultValue"


def sumValue():
    localValue = aggregateValue
    x = " mainValue"
    x1 = x + localValue
    localValue = " modifiedValue"
    x2 = x1 + localValue
    print(x2)
    return x2
```